# How to dynamically create and render a component in Ember JS 1.13+

Tags: javascript, ember.js

how can I dynamically create a component in ember 1.13.13. I want to create it programmaticaly, inside another component.

This used to work in Ember 1.11.

```
var component = this.get('container').lookupFactory("component:my-component");
var view = this.createChildView(component, {param1: 'param1'});
view.createElement();
Ember.$('body').append(view.element);

view.didInsertElement(); // manually call didInsertElement
```

The same piece of code doesn't work in ember 1.13+, and although it doesn't throw any errors, the component's `div` element is empty. It is like the template is not rendered. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Have you considered to use the `{{component 'name'}}` helper?

Comment: have a look at this "http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/programmatically-rendering-ember-components/6986/17" that may give you some insight

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer doing it from a function, and not using the component helper.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't, by design. I also suggest modelling it as data as using `{{component}}` as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions I received in the comments. I decided to rethink my components and use the `each` helper to get around this. I would advise everybody else to do the same.